# One-sample non-parametric test to test if a pre-specified quantile is greater than some value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

As the title says: is there a one-sample non-parametric test to test if a pre-specified quantile is greater than some given value?

Comment: This is called a "one sample test of proportions."  It uses the Binomial distribution.

Comment: @whuber: Thank you. Is that test the one implemented by quant.test (http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/snpar/html/quant.test.html)?If so please provide an answer and I am happy to deem it the correct answer.

Comment: It sounds like it from the description and the reference to the Binomial distribution.

Comment: Please post an answer and I am glad to mark it as the correct one.